# Does there exist a function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)/f(y)$ is a function of $x+y$?

Tags: calculus

Does there exist a real function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)/f(y)$ is a function of only $x+y$, for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Take $f = 1$...

Comment: One option if $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ is $f(x)=(-1)^x$.

Comment: @HenryW. Sorry, I meant for a non-constant function... But it seems that only constant function satisfies.

Comment: This problem is near to the condition of exponential function, though.

Comment: @Michael My proof crucially uses the fact that the set is not $\mathbb Z$, since if $x$ and $y$ are integers, then $\frac{x+y}{2}$ need not be an integer, so $f\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)$ is an invalid operation.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, yes I agree, your proof is right.

Comment: @Michael Thank you for the verification. However, your comment still has value, because it gives an  affirmative answer on a different set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $a$ and $b$ be any two real numbers. Since in your question, $y$ can be any real number, it follows that $f(y) \neq 0$ for all $y$, since division is permitted.

If $\frac{f(a)}{f(b)}$ depends only upon $a+b$, then since $a+b = \frac{a+b}{2} + \frac{a+b}2$, we have that: $\frac{f(a)}{f(b)} = \frac{f\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)}{f\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)} = 1$, since the expression $\frac{f\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)}{f\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)}$ depends only upon the sum of the operands, which is $a+b$.

Hence, $f(a) = f(b)$ for all $a,b$. It follows that $f$ is a constant function.

EDIT : This proof cannot be used to conclude that $\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}$ cannot non-trivially  depend on $x-y$.

The reason is simple: If $x+y$ can be fixed, then $x=y$ is possible, which allows us to determine the quotient.

However, if $x-y$ be fixed and non-zero, then $x=y$ is not possible, and nothing about the quotient can be concretely said.

For example, if $f(x) = e^x$, then $\frac{f(x)}{f(y)} = e^{x-y}$ depends only on $x-y$, a non-trivial solution. This is the crux of my proof.

Comment: (+1) essentially how I did this, except I simply set $b=0$. This answer got my upvote since you explicitly showed that $f$ cannot be $0$.

Comment: @robjohn Thank you very much! I added the edit so that I could point out the importance of why it works with $x+y$ and not with $x-y$. Yes, taking $b=0$ WLOG would also  be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Note that from $f(x)/f(y) = g(x+y)$ follows that:

- $f(x) \equiv f(0) \cdot g(x)$ (plugging $y=0$),
- $f(0) \equiv f(y) \cdot g(y)$ (plugging $x=0$).

If we combine these two equalities, we get that

$$ f(x) \equiv \bigl ( f(x) g(x) \bigr ) g(x) $$
or
$$ f(x) \cdot \bigl ( 1 - g(x)^2 \bigr ) \equiv 0. $$

If we want to avoid troubles with division by zero, then $f(x)$ is never zero, and from this follows that

$$ g(x)^2 - 1 = 0.$$

As @zwim noted, we can't straightforwardly jump to conclusion that $g(x) \equiv 1$ or $g(x) \equiv -1$. However, note that $1 \equiv f(x)/f(x) = g(2x)$. This holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (since we prohibited $f(x)$ for taking zero value). Thus, $g(x) \equiv 1$.

So, $f(x) = f(0)$ and constant non-zero functions are the only solutions for your problem.

Comment: I think there is something missing to end the proof. The implication that $f$ is constant is not immediate. For instance would it be possible that $f(x)=+1$ for $x$ in a certain set and $f(x)=-1$ for $x$ in the complementary set ?

Comment: @zwim Yeah, you are right. Somehow I forgot that I implicitly use that I'm looking only for continuous solutions. In that sense the other proof is better than mine: it doesn't use that asumption. Still I think I can fix mine)

Comment: @Evgeny You grasped  the general idea though! +1. (And now you have corrected the proof as well).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thank you! I still like your proof more :)

Comment: @zwim Seems that even continuity assumption is not needed here :))